# Dynamic mean calculation of float values using dask and groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dask

I'm trying to dynamically calculate the mean for all float64 columns. The end user should be able to filter through any of the category columns against a chart and get the various means for each instance. In order to achieve this, I've written the further below Python script using dask and groupby function.

However...

When performing groupby on the below columns, the object columns are vanished from the output CSV file as a result of aggregation and mean calculation on the columns containing float64 type. On this example, I'm using dask to read the dataframe (pandas is not an option due to high mem usage) and save the output file as CSV.

The dtypes of the input CSV columns are:

```
Dtype                   Columns
String (eg. 2018-P01/02) Time Period
Integer Journey Code
Object  Journey Name
Object  Route
Object  Route Name
Object  Area
Object  Area Name
Object  Fuel Type
Float64 Fuel Load
Float64 Mileage
Float64 Odometer Reading
Float64 Delay Minutes
```

My code for reading/saving the CSV and performing the mean calculation is:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

filename = "H:\\testing3.csv"
data = dd.read_csv("H:\\testing2.csv")
cols=['Time Period','Journey Code','Journey Name','Route',
      'Route Name','Area','Area Name','Fuel Type']
x = data.groupby(cols).aggregation(['mean'])
x.to_csv(filename, index = False)
```

An example of the original dataset is:

```
Time Period Journey Code    Route   Route Name      Area    Area Name
2018-P01    261803          High    France-Germany   WE       West
2018-P01-02 325429          High    France-Germany   EA      Eastern
2018-P01-02 359343          High    France-Germany   WCS    West Coast South
2018-P01-02 359343          High    France-Germany   WE     West
2018-P01-03 370697          High    France-Germany   WE     West
2018-P01-04 392535          High    France-Germany   EA     Eastern
2018-P01-04 394752          High    France-Germany   WCS    West Coast South
2018-P01-05 408713          High    France-Germany   WE     West

Fuel Type   Fuel Load   Mileage Odometer Reading    Delay Minutes
Diesel         165         6        14567.1               2
Diesel         210        12        98765.8               0
Diesel         210        5         23406.2               0
Diesel         130        10        54418.8               0
Diesel         152.5      37        58838.35              2
Diesel         142        140       63257.9              37.1194012
Diesel         131.5      120       67677.45              0
Diesel         121        13        72097                1.25
```

Why are the object columns vanishing from the resulting CSV file and how can I produce a result like the below?

Desired output (example on line 2 and 3): No average for the starting line but then any future float64 values will contain average (current against previous). I'm splitting each instance separately to get the dynamic result but any ideas are welcome.

```
    Time Period Journey Code    Route   Route Name  Area    Area Name

    2018-P01-02                 
                  325429                
                                 High           
                                        France-Germany      
                                                        EA  
                                                              Eastern
    …….                 

                   359343        High   France-Germany  WCS   West Coast South

Fuel Type   Fuel Load   Mileage Odometer Reading    Delay Minutes

Diesel         210        12        98765.8               0
Diesel         210        12        98765.8               0
Diesel         210        12        98765.8               0
Diesel         210        12        98765.8               0
Diesel         210        12        98765.8               0
......

Diesel         170        8.5       23406.2              NaN
```

> Edit: Added sample dataset in format of df.head(10).to_dict()

```
{'Time Period': {0: '2018-P01', 1: '2018-P01-02', 2: '2018-P01-02', 3: '2018-P01-02', 4: '2018-P01-03', 5: '2018-P01-04', 6: '2018-P01-04', 7: '2018-P01-05', 8: '2018-P01-06', 9: '2018-P01-07'}, 'Odometer Reading': {0: 14567.1, 1: 98765.8, 2: 23406.2, 3: 54418.8, 4: 58838.35, 5: 63257.9, 6: 67677.45, 7: 72097.0, 8: 89221.0, 9: 89221.0}, 'Journey Code': {0: 261803, 1: 325429, 2: 359343, 3: 359343, 4: 370697, 5: 392535, 6: 394752, 7: 408713, 8: 408714, 9: 408715}, 'Fuel Type': {0: 'Diesel', 1: 'Diesel', 2: 'Diesel', 3: 'Diesel', 4: 'Diesel', 5: 'Diesel', 6: 'Diesel', 7: 'Diesel', 8: 'Diesel', 9: 'Diesel'}, 'Route Name': {0: 'France-Germany', 1: 'France-Germany', 2: 'France-Germany', 3: 'France-Germany', 4: 'France-Germany', 5: 'France-Germany', 6: 'France-Germany', 7: 'France-Germany', 8: 'France-Germany', 9: 'France-Germany'}, 'Area': {0: 'WE', 1: 'EA', 2: 'WCS', 3: 'WE', 4: 'WE', 5: 'EA', 6: 'WCS', 7: 'WE', 8: 'WE', 9: 'WE'}, 'Route': {0: 'High', 1: 'High', 2: 'High', 3: 'High', 4: 'High', 5: 'High', 6: 'High', 7: 'High', 8: 'High', 9: 'High'}, 'Fuel Load': {0: 165.0, 1: 210.0, 2: 170.0, 3: 130.0, 4: 152.5, 5: 142.0, 6: 131.5, 7: 121.0, 8: 121.0, 9: 121.0}, 'Delay Minutes': {0: 2.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 2.0, 5: 37.119401200000006, 6: 0.0, 7: 1.25, 8: 2.56, 9: 2.56}, 'Mileage': {0: 6.0, 1: 12.0, 2: 8.5, 3: 10.0, 4: 37.0, 5: 140.0, 6: 120.0, 7: 13.0, 8: 13.0, 9: 13.0}, 'Area Name': {0: 'West', 1: 'Eastern', 2: 'West Coast South', 3: 'West', 4: 'West', 5: 'Eastern', 6: 'West Coast South', 7: 'West', 8: 'West', 9: 'West'}}
```

Comment: Do you mind to share the sample of your original df as `df.head(10).to_dict()`?

Comment: You can't have the mean of an `object` col. That's why they are not on the output. With `pandas` you are going to get the same

Comment: Sure, no problem at all, I'll get this uploaded ASAP. You can refer to the sample dataset attached further above as well. I've just had to split the columns (6 above and 5 below) for viewing purposes. I'm actually trying to calculate the mean on columns ('Fuel Load', 'Mileage', 'Odometer','Delay Minutes') which is calculated successfully but the grouping of category columns and their data is not included in the new CSV. I need this data to make my results dynamic.